# canvas html css js

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

¿Cómo puedo rotar un círculo sobre su propio eje en canvas como tipo animacion? tipo esto
[image: animacion de ejemplo]
debo realizar una animación en la que se muestra cómo se va construyendo un círculo usando el método arc y utlizando html css y js

```
HTML
<canvas id="circulo" width="300px" height="200px">
</canvas>

CSS

#circulo{
border: 1px solid red; 
background: lightgrey;
}

JS

var canvas= 
document.getElementById('circulo');
var ctx= canvas.getContext('2d');
var x=150;
var y=100;
var radius= 75;
var startAngle= 0;
var endAngle= 2 * Math.PI;
var counterClockwise= false;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x,y,radius,startAngle,endAngle,counterClockwise);
ctx.linewidth=10;
ctx.stokeStyle='black';
ctx.stoke();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion es de dibujar el circulo en partes y esperar un ratito con cada vez que se dibuja un parte. Cuando lo hagas con un intervalo de 100 milisegundos y marcas unos 0.1 rad a la vez, se vea bonito.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
   #circulo{
      border: 1px solid red;
      background: lightgrey;
   }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function loop(i) {
      setTimeout(function() {
          if (i < Math.PI * 2) {
             circulandose(i, i + 0.1);
             i = i + 0.1;
             loop(i); 
          }
      }, 100)
    }

   function circulandose(startAngle, endAngle) {

        var canvas = document.getElementById('circulo');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var x = 150;
        var y = 100;
        var radius = 75;
        var counterClockwise = false;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
        ctx.linewidth = 10;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.stroke();
   }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loop(0)">
    <canvas id="circulo" width="300px" height="200px">
    </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: De nada! Si viste util la respuesta, lo marcaras util para que otros que lo lean, saben lo tambien imediatamente. Gracias.